# Select tag is not working in Firefox browser when mouse click

Tags: html, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, mouse, angularjs-1.2

I am having various Select tags in my application. In Firefox browser all other select tags in different pages were working fine but I am having the only issue with this page.

When I try to change the option in select tag, it's not choosing.

I am binding the options for this select tag using Angular JS data-ng-option.

[image]

I am using the below code

[image]

**Edited:** When I tried to change the value through the Keyboard(Up and Down arrow) it's working fine. But I have only issue with the mouse clicking

Comment: might be as simple as a missing s at the end of data-ng-model, but its hard to tell whats happening just from a screenshot

Comment: What do you mean `not choosing`? Is the dropdown has `option`s and when you are trying to select one the value doesn't change? Can you show us the `userFilterChanged` code? Maybe it somehow change the selected option or re-render the dropdown to the initial state..

Comment: @MoshFeu No, the userFilterChanged method does not contain any code. I am yet to implement it but I have an empty method in my controller to avoid error.

Comment: Maybe do you a `$watch` on `data.discountCode`? Do you understand what I'm trying to find? A reason that the dropdown selected value will change. What is the chance that you can create a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) that reproduce the problem. Of course you don't have to use the real data, just use hardcoded values.

Comment: @MoshFeu When I tried to change the dropdown value through the keyboard(UP and down arrows), it's working fine. But when it changed through Mouse, it's not working.

Comment: Maybe there is a code that listen to a `click` event no the dropdown and does something. If you can create a snippet that reproduce the issue it will much easier because it's quite difficult the guess what wrong with your code "on blind"

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to each one of you for your help...

The issue is due to angular js plugin.

Currently, I am using 1.2.10. When I update it to < 1.2.15, it's working fine.